# Admob pods do not work after firebase integration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

As you may be aware of it, Google now switch to Firebase instead of Google Analytics. So I tried to integrate it to my current working project. Admob is also integrated to my project with Pods.
I have followed Google's document and created a new pod and re-install with firebase. After it , now my project does not build.
Here is error
Use of unresolved identifiers "GADBannerView"

Comment: Suggested an answer, but if that doesn't help could you paste in your Podfile (and confirm what version of Firebase you were using!)

Comment: please find my pods file source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
target “Instant Baby Sleep” do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end

Comment: I just tried that podfile and it worked ok. Can you check which version of cocoapods you are on (and upgrade to 1 if not)?

Comment: I have upgraded it to 1 and had problem. Regenerating pod file with latest  pod version has resolved that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it with:
-delete all pod related files from my project folder
-pod init
-re-add my required pods
-pod install

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your imports to just:

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
```

Everything should work as it was before, but using the module map is a great a way to pull in the headers rather than directly importing.

Comment: My project is a Swift file.

Comment: import GoogleMobileAds

Comment: Iain, thanks for answer but for surely I have imports before. This is not the issue. I have answered my question above.

Answer (score 0):

So I get this error as well with GADRequest errors even on Google's sample Banner project.

I fixed it with @Ian Barber's suggestion with @batgun's answer, of updating cocoapod version to 1.0.0 by running

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

then deleting all cocoapod items then install them again.

When I was in cocoapod version lower than 1.0.0, when I run pod install again, I still had errors, like "Use of unresolved identifier 'GADRequest'"

I retyped the whole thing and worked perfectly. When I was still not in cocoapod 1.0.0 version (i think it was 0.39 version), I can only find GADRequestError and not GADRequest.

When I retry extracting the original project now, do pod install and run the app, It doesn't throw any errors now.

I believe this has something to do with cocoapod version but it is not in google admob instruction to update it on.

I was trying to figure this out since the day of the release and losing hope for firebase because it was the sample basic banner project and it doesn't work!

**VERIFIED!**

I can verify it has something to do with cocoapod version.

I was trying to do the Google's Codelab 'FriendlyChatSwift' practice project since the release and throws a bunch of errors after running pod, not finding bunch of classes.

**Steps:**

1. `$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods`
2. I deleted the existing downloaded pods and related (ProjectName.xcworkspace, PodFile.lock, /Pods)
3. Run pod install
4. Build and Run of the project

It worked perfectly. I also tried running the project before doing this steps and It had bunch of errors.

Comment: It wouldn't work by just deleting all pod related items and installing them again. I did that a couple of times even before seeing your solution when my cocoapod was still in version 0.39. Did not work. Only worked when I updated my cocoapod to 1.0. I should've mention your answer. I'll do that

Comment: I said I have already updated to v1.0 but after that it completely broken because previous pod file is not compatible

Comment: From what happened to mine, If you already installed the pod with the lower version (mine was 0.39) of cocoapod, then updating cocoapod to 1.0.0, it still won't work without re-installing the pod. On the other hand, re-installing the cocoapod only, without updating the cocoapod version to 1.0.0 didn't work either. So, updating the cocoapod to 1.0.0 then reinstalling is the one that works, hence the steps I stated to fix mine

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and this helped me get setup the way I needed it but I don't think anyone touched on my exact issue.  Thought I'd provide that just in case someone was looking.

After I cleared everything out and ran `pod init` I noticed that the generated pod file has `use_frameworks!` set in it. Once I added that everything was solved.  Stupid mistake on my part since you need `use_frameworks!` for swift projects but leaving that out lead to a lot of random not found errors showing up and going away at random. Hope this helps someone.