# Firebase failed to import bridging header

Tags: swift, firebase, bridging-header

I’m going crazy here. Trying to update my swift iOS app with the new firebase. Followed all the steps to instal with cocoa pods but keep getting ‘Firebase/Firebase.h’  file not found & failed to import bridging header.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to add the path on *User Header Search Paths* to the folder where the `Firebase.h` file is?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your cocoapod to latest version 1.0.0 by running

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

1. I deleted the existing downloaded pods and related (ProjectName.xcworkspace, PodFile.lock, /Pods)
2. Run pod install
3. Build and Run of the project

It fixed several errors for me on admob/firebase not finding several classes that is on the SDK.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37401069/2365714